# Google sites content taking up entire window

Tags: html, css, google-sites

I am working on a Google site for a school project. However, the site looks like[image: broken site]

instead of [image: working site]

I did not add the extra stuff, Google sites added it for me. Is there any way to get rid of it?

```css
.titlebox {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.map {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.content {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
a div {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px;
}
a:hover div {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="titlebox">
  <h1>GMO DEBATE</h1>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <div text-align="center">
    <h3>pages:</h3>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="pro">
        <div>why GMOs should be labeled</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="con">
        <div>why GMOs shouldn't be labeled</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="info">
        <div>background information</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h3>Should GMOs be labeled?</h3>
</div>
```

That is in a code box, although I don't think it matters since the extra stuff was there before I even added anything. Adding a width to the elements does not help.

Comment: We'll need to see your code. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Have you tried setting a width to .map?

Comment: adding a width does not help. I believe that nothing I do in code will help, and that the solution (if it exists) would be something else

Comment: @Lucas can you send your site link

Answer (score 0):

As you said its **code box** in code box you can display your content only in limited area you will be allotted only some give space `75%` or `70%` of page display area.

If you need Your website on full page like as you want find a free host site like http://www.000webhost.com and host you web pages you can do what ever you want